# How to evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}}$ by $f(z)=\frac{\cot(\pi z)}{z^{2}}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I got there is pole of order $3$ at $z=0$ and order 1 at $z=k$ where k is non-zero integer.

When $z=k$, $\operatorname{Res}(f;k)=\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k^{2}}$. Then I'm stucked here. It seems I can only evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n^{2}}$.

Comment: As $\cot$ is $\pi$-periodic, how do you get the $(-1)^k$ ?

Comment: Oh I see where I'm wrong... Thank you

Comment: If you were correct, you would still be able to evaluate the sum since $$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n^2 }}}  + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^n }}{{n^2 }}}  = 2\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{(2n)^2 }}}  = \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n^2 }}}  \Rightarrow \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n^2 }}}  =  - 2\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^n }}{{n^2 }}} .
$$